# Javascript call function - Dynamic variable name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function using a variable with it's name.

Here's the code:

```
var selectedFunc = 'func2';

var myModule = {

    func1: function() {
       //something here  
    },

    func1: function() {
       //something here 
    }

};

myModule.selectedFunc();
```

I would normally do this:

```
myModule.func1();
```

which will work but I'm trying to use the variable to define it's name, which is not working.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bracket notation:

```
myModule[selectedFunc]();
```

Comment: Surely you didn't think this hasn't been asked before...

Answer (score 0):

Use eval.

```
var selectedFunc = 'func2';

var myModule = {

    func1: function() {
       return "hello";
    },

    func2: function() {
       return "world"; 
    }

};

window.alert(eval("myModule." + selectedFunc + "()"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call it using the following syntax

```
setTimeout("myModule."+selectedFunc + "()", 0);
```

Or even using eval to call it

```
eval("myModule." + selectedFunc).call();
```